# Intersecting GraphicsPath objects

Tags: .net, winforms, gdi+, gdi

How can I intersect two (.NET) GraphicsPath objects?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to get the area enclosed by two different paths? That is a `Region`, not a path:

```
var rgn1 = new Region(path1);
var intersection = rgn1.Intersect(path2);
rgn1.Dispose();
```

If that is not what you mean, you will have to provide more information.

Comment: Already tried that. Unfortunately when I try to fill that rectangle I get some strange visual glitches. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: What are you "filling"? And Regions are not rectangles. Please show the source code.

Comment: Regions don't support Antialiasing - that is what you might see.