# Clipping GraphicsPath with another GraphicsPath

Tags: c#, gdi+, gdi

How do you Clip a `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath` with another `GraphicsPath` to get **a new GraphicsPath**?

Note 1: It is possible to SetClip() a whole `System.Drawing.Graphics` object, but what is needed here is some sort of Intersecting a GraphicsPath to get another GraphicsPath.

Note 2: The method discussed here ([Intersecting GraphicsPath objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503376/intersecting-graphicspath-objects)) returns a region. Here we expect a GraphicsPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick go at this, and the closest I got was this:

```
var region = new Region(gp1);
region.Intersect(gp2);

var gpResult = new GraphicsPath();
gpResult.AddRectangles(region.GetRegionScans(new Matrix()));
gpResult.CloseAllFigures();

using (var br = new SolidBrush(Color.LightYellow))
{
    e.Graphics.FillPath(br, gpResult);
    //e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, gpResult);
}
```

The problem with this is that `GetRegionScans()` gives you thousands of rectangles back, not just the distinct points of the lines.  Uncomment the DrawPath method to see what I mean.

There is an open source library for manageing clipping, which seems to be reasonably active [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/polyclipping/) (Found via [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272179/a-simple-algorithm-for-polygon-intersection)).

I have no experience with it, but it looks to be able to do what you are after.

Comment: I prefer the external library. This code from its demo is the solution:

  Polygons solution2 = new Polygons();
  Clipper c = new Clipper();
  c.UseFullCoordinateRange = false;
  c.AddPolygons(subjects, PolyType.ptSubject);
  c.AddPolygons(clips, PolyType.ptClip);
  exSolution.Clear();
  solution.Clear();
  c.Execute(GetClipType(), solution, GetPolyFillType(), GetPolyFillType());